# Warning: copy() [function.copy]: Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php

I'm uploading a .PDF and .ZIP file via a HTML form then passing it to my PHP script where the file is moved from the temp folder and placed in a specified folder. Now this works great on files under 2mb, anything over I will get the following error message:

```
Warning: copy() [function.copy]: Filename cannot be empty
```

The filename isn't empty and the code works fine for files under 2mb in size.

I checked my php.ini file in /etc/ folder (im running centos6.4) and in its config I have

```
 upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

I'm thinking this is still a PHP config issue thats causing the error on files over 2mb, is there any other config I need to be looking at?

```
<?php
session_start();
$ref = $_POST['doc_ref'];
$rev = $_POST['doc_rev'];
$owner = $_POST['doc_owner'];
$contract = $_POST['contract'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$pdf = $_FILES['pdf'];
$zip = $_FILES['zip'];
$pdf_name = $_FILES['pdf']['name'];
$content = $_POST['doc_content'];
$userid = $_SESSION['users_id'];
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = date_create();

// get the pdf from the form then remove the extension
$title = $_FILES["pdf"]["name"];
$title = pathinfo($title,PATHINFO_FILENAME);


$sth = "SELECT * FROM `contracts` WHERE `contracts_id`='$contract'";
$result = $conn->query($sth);   
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $contract_name = $row['contracts_name'];
    $contract_prefix = $row['prefix'];
}

if ($contract_prefix)
{
    if ($type === '1')
    {
    $zippath = "zips/" . $contract_prefix . "/" . $contract_name . "/Forms/";
    $arcpath = "arc/" . $contract_prefix . "/" . $contract_name . "/Forms/";
    $pdfpath = "pdfs/" . $contract_prefix . "/" . $contract_name . "/Forms/";
    }elseif ($type === '2')
    {
    $zippath = "zips/" . $contract_prefix . "/" . $contract_name . "/Work Instructions And Process Flows/";
    $arcpath = "arc/" . $contract_prefix . "/" . $contract_name . "/Work Instructions And Process Flows/";
    $pdfpath = "pdfs/" . $contract_prefix . "/" . $contract_name . "/Work Instructions And Process Flows/";
    }
}else
{
    if ($type === '1')
    {
    $zippath = "zips/" . $contract_name . "/Forms/";
    $arcpath = "arc/" . $contract_name . "/Forms/";
    $pdfpath = "pdfs/" . $contract_name . "/Forms/";
    }elseif ($type === '2')
    {
    $zippath = "zips/" . $contract_name . "/Work Instructions And Process Flows/";
    $arcpath = "arc/" . $contract_name . "/Work Instructions And Process Flows/";
    $pdfpath = "pdfs/" . $contract_name . "/Work Instructions And Process Flows/";
    }
}

$pdfpath = $pdfpath . $_FILES["pdf"]["name"];
$zippath = $zippath . $_FILES["zip"]["name"];
// create archpath to store for later use
$arcpathfinal = $arcpath;
// append the current revision to the start of the zip files name for the arc
$arcpath = $arcpath . "Revision " . $rev . " - " . $_FILES["zip"]["name"];

//check the uploaded file is in PDF format and then move to correct directory
$allowed =  array('pdf');
$pdf = $_FILES['pdf']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($pdf, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'The file type must be a PDF!';
}else
{
    // move zip and pdf into correct folders
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"], $pdfpath);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["zip"]["tmp_name"], $zippath);
}

// make a copy of zip file into arc folder
copy($zippath, $arcpath);

//INSERTING INTO DATABASE CODE HERE
```

**UPDATE**

Ok I have been doing a bit of testing, the $_FILES array seems to be empty when the filesize is over 2MB, under 2MB the array returns the name, type, tmp_name, error, size as expected.

What would the reason be the $_FILES is empty with files over 2MB. Yes my upload_max_filesize is set higher than the file size and my post_max_size is set higher than my upload_max_filesize. Yes I have restarted Apache after making changes to the php.ini file

Comment: You are probably not able to upload files greater than 2MB. Which causes your target path to miss a filename and your origin path also. That's why the copy fails. You will have to validate that move_uploaded_file actually succeeded before continuing with the copy action.

Comment: Little tip. Just because you use PDO doesn't mean you're safe. You're not. You should use pre compiled statements with bound parameters, or whatever they're called. What if `$contract` was `'; DROP TABLE contracts; --lulz`? It would give me zeequel injwecshun.

Comment: @ColeJohnson prepared statements that is :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes thank you, I was binding parameters using named place holders when it came to inserting the final data but not for the select statement above. Its only a closed personal project but its certainty something I will be vigilant about going forward

Answer (score 5):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize.

Comment: There's also the limitation of the web server itself. If you aren't allocated enough memory per process, it won't work.

Comment: thank you, I've tried this but its not made a difference, @Cole Johnson, can you point me in the direction of where this limitation is located?

Comment: @twigg There is no way to change that limitation. If you're web hosted has set such a limit, you're SOL. If they didn't, the closest you can get is increasing the memory (RAM) of the server.

Comment: @ColeJohnson thanks cole, well it shouldn't be an issue because its my local server and it has 24GB ram so that should cover the 15mb file im trying to upload, this one really has me stumped for now, it has to be another config setting I'm guessing.