# php image copy from one folder to another with copy function

Tags: php, file-handling

i'm trying to copy image from one folder to another folder with the php copy function, but i'm getting this error:
`Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty` ,pls kindly help fix this or recommend better way of doing this. thanks. I'v tried using the code below:

```
   $images = "images/b4uploads/image.jpg";
    $p = basename($images);
    $dest  = 'images/uploaded/'.$p;
    copy($images,$dest);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236026/warning-copy-function-copy-filename-cannot-be-empty

Comment: @RanjeetSingh that is not the issue in this question, thanks.

Comment: you should `var_dump` both values (`$images` and `$dest`) before they're used by `copy`. This will tell you exactly what's being given to the copy function. (*edit your Q*)

Comment: I am programing PHP for 15 years lol and I find this question good. Variables evaluate to `copy("images/b4uploads/image.jpg", "images/uploaded/image.jpg");` PHP expects two strings as parameters, none of them is empty, the warning makes no sense?!

Comment: Only thing I can image is a problem with relative path not beeing available or one of the directories does not exist. Try absolute paths and use `file_exists()` on both, source and destination.